# How to stop infinite scroll when data is no longer codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

hi am having a problem with infinite scroll functionality, when all the contents have been displayed it still continues to scroll (strange behavior). i am looking for a way to stop the infinite scroll when all contents are displayed

here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var total_record = 0;
        var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;

        $('#results').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/csr_transactions/get_products",
            {'group_no':total_record}, function() {total_record++;});

        $(window).scroll(function() { 
    });

        $('#load_more').click(function(){
            load_more(total_record, total_groups);
        });


        function load_more(total_record, total_groups) {
            if(total_record <= total_groups)
            {
                $('.loader_image').show(); 
                $.post('<?php echo site_url() ?>admin/csr_transactions/get_products',{'group_no': total_record},
                    function(data)
                    { 
                        if (data != "") {                               
                            $("#results").append(data);                 
                            $('.loader_image').hide();                  
                            total_record++;
                        }

                    });     
            }
        }





    });
</script>`
```

Comment: Check `data` for a particular response to stop infinite scroll.

Comment: I think your problem here is that ajax is triggered which means it runs in parallel and never updates your total_records. Test it by putting an `alert(total_records);` after your `total_records++`. Your better solution would be to store total_records as a data-tag on a field. Let me know how you get on and I can create an answer if that works.